# Move mentioned user from one voice channel to another (Discord.js)

Tags: discord

I promise, I've tried everything. I think I have the actually command down, but I can't figure out how to implement the name of the voice channel. Here's my code:

```
if (!message.mentions.users.first()) {
            message.channel.send("You have to tag someone my dude.")
            break;
}
var member = (message.mentions.users.first())
guild.member(member).setVoiceChannel(Rats)
message.channel.send(":right_facing_fist: " + member)
break;
```

It runs through just fine, but "Rats" (the voice channel) is undefined. Do I need a variable that has the voice channel name? Is there something else I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you show the assignment codes for variable `Rats` in the argument of `setVoiceChannel()`?

Comment: I had tried a few different ways of using `var Rats = voiceChannel.name(supercoolvoicechannelname)` but I didn't know how to do that either.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your code is fine to me, but the Assignment of `Rats` is wrong.

`setVoiceChannel()` method takes in an argument which is a `channel` with type `voice`. So all you have to do is just directly assign the `voiceChannel` object to `Rats` and it would work.

You can get the list of channels in a guild by `message.guild.channels`, which returns a `Collection<Snowflake,Guildchannel>`. From there, you can filter out all the non-VCs using `filter` . You can do `channel.type === "voice"` to check if a channel is a voice channel or not.